# windows python interpreter kills C++ worker threads silently on exit

Tags: python, c++, multithreading

I have a Python extension module written in C++. In the module, there are some worker threads doing some cleaning work in the background. I need to make sure the cleaning is actually done before exiting the application, which I check in the destructor of a static variable.

The code works perfectly when called from C++: the cleaning is always done properly and the application exits successfully. However, when run from Python, the main thread will stuck in the destructor waiting for the cleaning. I attach to the process and found that the worker threads are killed (which should not happen), leaving no one to do the cleaning work, which then blocks the main thread. This seem to happen only on Windows, but not Linux. On linux, everything works just fine.

**My guess is that the Python interpreter on Windows somehow kills all threads except for the master thread when it exits, and then the destructor of static variables comes after that. In that case, the workers are already killed and there is no one to clean up the remaining garbage, thus the main thread hangs waiting for the cleanup. May someone shed some light on this?**

Here is the config I am using:
Hangs:  Windows 10 x64, Visual Studio 2017, Python 3.7 x64
Works:  Ubuntu 16.04 x64, gcc 5.5, Python 3.5.2 x64

Here is a piece of code demonstrating what I am doing:

```
class TestThread {
    std::atomic<int> num_items_;
    std::atomic<bool> exit_;
    std::thread t_;

    TestThread() :
        num_items_(0),
        exit_(false)
    {
        t_ = std::thread([this]() {
            while (!exit_) {
                if (!num_items_) {
                    // sleep for some time
                }
                else {
                    // do the work
                    num_items_--;
                }
            };
        });
    }
public:
    ~TestThread() {
        num_items_ = 1;
        while (num_items_) sleep(1);  // main thread waits till all jobs are done
                                      // this hangs when invoked from Python interpreter, 
                                      // but works just fine when called from C++
        exit_ = true;
        t_.join();
    }

    static TestThread& GetInstance() {
        static TestThread t;
        return t;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    auto& tt = TestThread::GetInstance();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since you are probably using the C implementation of python, it is more likely that it is the C run-time library kiling the threads.  See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100827-00/?p=13023/

Comment: Thanks to @cdarke . I see what is happening here. When the Python interpreter exits, it somehow calls ExitProcess, which kills the worker thread, and the cleaning of static variables happens after that, causing the program to hang. I added a macro around the destructor of TestThread, so if it is Windows, I just do the remaining cleaning job manually in the destructor. It seems to work. I am not sure if it is the best solution though: the worker threads can be in a dirty state when it was killed. Is there a way to guarantee correctness?

Comment: There are other ways to do it, `DLL_THREAD_DETACH` in your Windows `DllMain`, but that's called for every thread (even those who don't use the DLL), so you need to code checks that the resources have been allocated before trying to tidy them.